# Django 1.11.4 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL does not work

Tags: django, redirect, authentication

I am changing an existing Django app..

MacOS OSX 10.13.6 , Django 1.11.4 and 1.11.3

The setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` apparently has no effect.

I am logging in as an admin. **What I wanted is to go to a specific page after the user logs in ( instead of admin interface with model links)**. `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` seems to be ignored. Even if I set it to bogus, there's no error and I end up on Admin page with the links to the models. Maybe I just did not understand the docs about its functionality.

The docs states:

> The URL where requests are redirected after login when the
>   contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter

In the POST request in browser inspect tool I see "next=/login/", I don't know if this is bad and how to get rid of it.

There seems to several threads on SO on the subject for older versions of Django, and they did not help.

- Setting `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` does not change
  the behaviour
- Setting `APPEND_SLASH = True` does not change
  the behaviour
- Removing "login"-matching entry from `urlpatterns` list does not change the behaviour.
- Adding `url(r'myapp/admin/',myview)` to `urlpatterns` does not have any effect either.
- Appending and / or prepending a slash to the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting in `setting.py` or to regex in `urls.py` manually has no effect. Also tried to start with caret in regex

The code:

in `settings.py`:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'myapp/myview'
```

in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    # this works if clicked from the Menu on admin screen
    # , but I would like this url to be used also as default landing page after the user logs in 
    url(r'^myapp/myview', myview),         
    # this being present or removed makes no difference
    url(r'login', admin.site.urls, name="Login"),
    # probably useless 
    url(r'myapp/admin/',myview),
    .....
    .....
]
```

I have several views.py in diferent subdirs, they are all imported. One of them contains

```
@login_required
def myview(request):
  # my code
```

and it works fine when clicked on its link from the Menu, i.e. url pattern  `r'^myapp/myview'` matches and the view loads. That makes me think that LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting is completely ignored after the login action.

Thanks

Comment: Post your views.py.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi I have several views.py in several subdirectories, that's couple of thousand lines. They are all imported to urls.py. One of them contains: 
```@login_required
def myview(request):
   # code
```
and it works when pointed at from Menu (i.e. loads the view)

Answer (score 0):

You can this way;

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but that had no effect. What is '/accounts/login' anyway? I do't think I arrive to the point of routing to myveiw (and its decorator), login sends me directly to admin page from inside of the login code.

Comment: Thanks to this code, you can use it without login_url and login_redirect_url in settings.py, if you try it you will see ...